# writing output data into excel file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 50 images, I want to write data into text file in matlab for each image column wise but when I run the programe it will write data only one image value.

```
srcFiles = dir('E:\practice \\*.jpg');
for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
  filename = strcat('E:\practice\',srcFiles(i).name);
  I = imread(filename);
  B=bwlabel(I);
  D=regionprops(B,'MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength','Extent');
  j=D.MajorAxisLength;
  k=D.MinorAxisLength;
  Axialratio=j/k
  ex=[D.Extent]
  fid=fopen('mu.txt ','wt+');
  fprintf(fid,'extent  Axialratio\n');
  fprintf(fid,'%6f     %6f \n',[ex,Axialratio]);
  fclose(fid);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `fopen` with `wt+` option. First of all, there is no such option. Maybe you meant `w+`. Documentation says:

```
Open or create new file for reading and writing. Discard existing contents, if any.
```

So you are discarding content every time you enter into a `for` loop for each image. Do the following:

```
srcFiles = dir('E:\practice \\*.jpg');
fid=fopen('mu.txt ','w+');
for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
  filename = strcat('E:\practice\',srcFiles(i).name);
  I = imread(filename);
  B=bwlabel(I);
  D=regionprops(B,'MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength','Extent');
  j=D.MajorAxisLength;
  k=D.MinorAxisLength;
  Axialratio=j/k
  ex=[D.Extent]

  fprintf(fid,'extent  Axialratio\n');
  fprintf(fid,'%6f     %6f \n',ex,Axialratio); //Also don't create a matrix, you could have written it as two separate quantities as I have done now.
 end 
fclose(fid);
```

This should work.